# compare date stored in varchar in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am getting one issue,
I am trying to fetch all records whose date is less than current date,
but problem is date stored in **`15-Nov-13`** formate(in varchar(20))

now how to compare it?

I tried

```
SELECT date_format( str_to_date( `ENDdatetime` , '%d/%M/%y' ) , '%Y%m' ) , `CLIENT_PROMO_ID`
FROM `tb_um_promo_schedule`
ORDER BY `CLIENT_PROMO_ID` DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

but it returns NULL,

so what to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format you gave in your question (`15-Nov-13`) does not match the format you are trying to convert in this:

```
'%d/%M/%y'
```

Should it not be

```
'%d-%M-%y'
```

instead?

```
SELECT date_format( str_to_date( `ENDdatetime` , '%d-%M-%y' ) , '%Y%m' ) , `CLIENT_PROMO_ID`
FROM `tb_um_promo_schedule`
ORDER BY `CLIENT_PROMO_ID` DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: @Er.KT No problems, sometimes a second set of eyes picks things up nice and quick.

Comment: as a side note do not store date in varchar format. Use datetime else it becomes very difficult for query operations and u need many conversion functions.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty yeah i know but i got this project in mid so now can not change whole things

Comment: @Er.KT Well, not sure how much code hits that table - but you can convert the data in it quite easily if you can update the functions that touch it.

Comment: exactly u can write a small script to update all the dates and that will make ur life far more easy.